# SharePoint Lists - Alternate Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, custom-form, powerapps-forms

I am working with a SharePoint List at the moment. The list manages the workflow for a number of different departments due to the nature of the business. Is it possible to create alternate forms for each SharePoint List view? Is this something that I would normally do via Power Apps? I can see that there is no way to change the form format for each view in SharePoint.

To confirm, we use the SharePoint Online environment.

We require multiple views as there are a number of different processes that the business goes through, and it would be really handy if each team could see only the fields that they are required to fill out in their form within their specific view.

Any advice and assistance would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can set a field visible or not based on the current user in Power Apps.

You could change the Visible property of the corresponding DataCard with the code below:

```
If(User().FullName="UserFulName",true, false)
```

Or in the following format:

```
If(User().FullName in ["User Name 1", "User Name 2",....],true, false)
```

The code would check if the UserName matches the one specified, or within the User Name table, if yes, show the DataCard, otherwise, this data card would be invisible.

By the way, you should also replace `User().FullName` with `Office365Users.MyProfile().DisplayName`.

Comment: So sorry for the delay in replying to this forum. We have been so busy and had some time off for the holidays.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistancec, I will give this a go and let you know how it works